# node exceljs is writing 0 byte file

Tags: node.js, macos, append, xlsx, exceljs

I'm trying to append an array of integers as a row to an xlsx file. What I have creates the file and doesn't produce an error, but my file explorer (OS X) then says that the produced file is zero bytes and Microsoft Excel for Mac will not even open it.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('rssi');
file = 'rssi_values.xlsx'
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
sheet.addRow(array)         
workbook.xlsx.writeFile(file)
.then(function() {
    console.log('Array added and file saved.')
});
```

also tried adding, in addition to the above (same output):

```
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('rssi');
sheet.columns = [
    { header: "Beacon 1", key: "r1", width: 10 },
    { header: "Beacon 2", key: "r2", width: 10 },
    { header: "Beacon 3", key: "r3", width: 10 },
    { header: "Beacon 4", key: "r4", width: 10 }
];
sheet.addRow({r1: array[0], r2: array[1], r3: array[2], r4: array[3]})
```

Is this package broken or incompatible, or am I just not using it properly?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem - only on localhost

Comment: Sorry, I honestly can't remember what I did about this